# How to make the output of a print statement be delayed in displaying for a second?

Tags: java

So here I just have a simple Java program that calculates the numbers of the Fibonacci sequence. It works well. There are no bugs. The program asks the user how many numbers of the Fibonacci sequence the user wants to see. The only noticeable "issue" here is that the numbers are almost spontaneously calculated and displayed. If the user asks for a very large amount of numbers, they are all displayed. Then the user has to scroll up to read them all from the beginning. I think that it would be good to delay the println statements that display the numbers for a second for readability. The user would have an opportunity to read each number one at a time! What would be the professional way to achieve this effect? I need a statement that causes the program to wait for a little bit after each number is displayed. What should I add to my code? Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FibonacciModified {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("This program will print out the ");
    System.out.println("Fibonacci sequence of numbers.");
    System.out.print("\n");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many numbers do you want?");
    int numbers = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\n");
    int num1 = 0, num2 = 1, num3;
    for (int z = 0; z < numbers; z++) {
        switch (z) {
            case 0:
            System.out.println(num1);
            break;
            case 1:
            System.out.println(num2);
            break;
            default:
            num3 = num1 + num2;
            System.out.println(num3);
            num1 = num2;
            num2 = num3;
            break;
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: In my opinion outputting your calculation to a file would be the ideal solution.

Comment: Let the user choose. Let them pipe the output to `more`, e.g. `java FibonacciModified | more`. Now they will get one page at a time. Or `java FibonacciModified | less` for pagination support (scroll back/forward). Or ... In short: Let the user choose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FibonacciModified {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("This program will print out the ");
    System.out.println("Fibonacci sequence of numbers.");
    System.out.print("\n");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many numbers do you want?");
    int numbers = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\n");
    int num1 = 0, num2 = 1, num3;
    for (int z = 0; z < numbers; z++) {
        switch (z) {
            case 0:
            System.out.println(num1);
            break;
            case 1:
            System.out.println(num2);
            break;
            default:
            num3 = num1 + num2;
            System.out.println(num3);
            num1 = num2;
            num2 = num3;
            break;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000); // 1000 is 1 sec
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `Thread.sleep(1000)` (1000 is for milliseconds, you could also do `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1)` to be more explicit) after the `for`:

```
  for (int z = 0; z < numbers; z++) {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
```

You will need to add `InterruptedException` to the `throws` of main or handle the exception in a try block, example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
```

Comment: NetBeans shows this error: unreported exception InteruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown.

Comment: I wrote above that you will need to handle it, and I've added an example (changing the main method signature).

Answer (score 1):

You can also go with the below after each iteration of your loop:

> TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);//Stops execution of one sec

The above internally calls **Thread.sleep()**. The only added advantage you would have here is that you don't need to calculate the number of milliseconds you want to stop the execution which is required for Thread.sleep(milliseconds) to work.

TimeUnit gives the flexibility to pause the program execution from NANOSECONDS to DAYS.

Comment: That's good, but it doesn't accept decimals such as 0.5. When the type cast operator is used, this code does not wait.

Comment: @Galaxy if you'd want to stop the execution for half a second then you'd use it like this.... TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);       this will stop the execution for half a sec. TimeUnit always accepts long type of variables for it's sleep method.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is pause the main thread with `Thread.sleep(milliseconds)`

For example, right after your for loop:

```
for (int z = 0; z < numbers; z++) {
    Thread.sleep(500);
    switch (z) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below method, and call this method on all the places you are calling `System.out.println`.

```
public void printWithSleep(int x){
  try{
     Thread.sleep(1000);
     System.out.println(x);

  } catch(Exception e){
    //Eat or print the exception
  }

}
```